# Tem como atualizar todo o banco de dados com eloquent do laravel(API)?

Tags: laravel, api

Estou criando uma api e estou querendo criar um metódo que atualiza tudo porem não 
sei se o eloquent tem este recurso. É porque criei um app(offline) que me manda todos os dados de uma vez para atualizar no banco.

Answer (score 0):

O Eloquent tem uma estrutura bem robusta e o laravel fornece algumas facilidades nativas para API's. Nunca usei pra atualizar todo o banco mas conheço duas formas de atualizar banco de forma massiva no eloquent migrations e seeds:

- [Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations) é para criar ou modificar estruturas, creio que não é o que você procura mas de qualquer forma, fica o link.
- [Seeds](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/seeding) envia dados para o banco, até onde sei só faz inserts, não usei de outra forma. Uma classe do tipo seed atualiza uma ou várias tabelas com dados e pode perfeitamente ser acessada via API.
  Você pode estudar a estrutura dessa classe, criar o arquivo de envio para o banco e liberar o acesso dela via API, acho que resolve. Ah, provavelmente tem alguma coisa pronta para gerar esse arquivo no laravel.